# Image not loading on webpage

Tags: html

The image will load when I open the page locally, but when i go to the ip the image is not loaded. the image is in the same directory as the html file.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/JavaScript">
    var img = new Image;

    img.onload = function(){
        var canvas = document.getElementById("can");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        setTimeout(loadImage, 1000);
    };

    function loadImage(){
        img.src = 'image.jpg';
    }

    </script>

        <title>Page</title>
    </head>
    <body onload="JavaScript:loadImage();">
        <canvas id="can" width="1280" height="720" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does your browser's console say when it doesn't load? BTW, `onload="JavaScript:loadImage();` should be just `onload="loadImage();`. Come to think of it, why does this function even exist at all? Just put `img.src = 'image.jpg';` in your other onload function.

Comment: Try `img.src = '/image.jpg';`

Answer (score 1):

I really hope this solution will work for you i just edited the root of the image by adding slash symbol and changed onload="loadImage();" function

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/JavaScript">
    var img = new Image;

    img.onload = function(){
        var canvas = document.getElementById("can");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        setTimeout(loadImage, 1000);
    };

    function loadImage(){
        img.src = '/image.jpg';
    }

    </script>

        <title>Page</title>
    </head>
    <body onload="loadImage();">
        <canvas id="can" width="1280" height="720" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Answers which explain what has been changed and why are generally up voted more and down voted less than those which offer no explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Relative path in javascript usually had unexpected results for me and if it worked in one browser it was much likely to don't work in one another browser. I found that it is much convenient to store root address in a config file and make absolute path instead of relative paths.

```
const contentsBaseAddress = 'http://localhost:80/contents/'

function loadImage(){
    img.src = contentsBaseAddress + 'images/myImage.jpg';
}
```